# Swift parsing json and data transmission

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I'm beginner to developing for iOS.
Before me is the task of using api GitHub to get data about description of user's Gists.

The idea is this:
I enter the username in `usernameTextField` on the first `viewcontroller` (`LoginViewController`)
And you press **searchTapped**, the segue is triggered and throws you into the second viewcontroller (`GistsViewController`), where in the `tableview` is displayed the description received from `json`
Data from the json is decoded and added to the *gists* array, and then it is passed through the segue to the `GistsViewController`.
But the project is going without errors, while it does not work as it should .. Can someone help me edit my code?

This is my model:

```
struct Gists: Codable {
    let description: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description

    }
}
```

this is the first viewController:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    var gists = [String]()
    var username: String?

    func displayWarningLabel(withText text: String) {
        warningLabel.text = text
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.warningLabel.alpha = 1
        }) { [weak self] complete in
            self?.warningLabel.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        warningLabel.alpha = 0
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToMainScreen(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        usernameTextField.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func searchTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text, username != "" else {
            displayWarningLabel(withText: "Information is incorrect")
            return
        }

        guard let gitUrl = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(username)/gists") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl) { (data, response, error) in 
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let gitData = try decoder.decode([Gists].self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    self.gists.append(gitData.description)
                }
            } catch let err {
                print("Err", err)
            }
            }.resume()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let dvc = segue.destination as? GistsViewController else { return }
        dvc.username = usernameTextField.text
        dvc.gists1 = gists
        }
}
```

and this is second viewController:

```
class GistsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var username: String!
    var gists1 = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gists1.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.textLabel?.text = gists1[indexPath.row]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = username
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        print(gists1)
    }

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }     
}
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)` is called too soon. `dataTask(with:completion:)` is asynchronous. That's the concept your are missing. Look for "Asynchone + Swift + Closure".

Comment: I correctly understood you, that the method 'performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)' works earlier, than time to register the data in an array? Perhaps you have ideas how to change my approach to this task?

Answer (score 0):

The call to api is asynchronous , so insert `performSegue` inside the completion block

```
guard let gitUrl = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(username)/gists") else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let gitData = try decoder.decode([Gists].self, from: data)

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.gists.append(contentsOf:gitData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    } catch let err {
        print("Err", err)
    }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I did not notice any changes in the application's performance.
Data is retrieved, but not stored in an array. And accordingly on the second viewController an empty array is transferred. How can this be remedied?

Comment: I think you need to append **gitData** not **gitData.description** , see edit ..... , also make sure that button **searchTapped** is not the source of the segue